# Extending a model's class methods via a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to write a gem that will allow me to call class methods on Rails models. So far, I have the following:

*mygem/models/active_record_extension.rb*

```
module ActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      "foo"
    end
  end
end
# Include the extension 
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

I'm requiring this file as follows:

```
require "mygem/version"
require "mygem/models/active_record_extension"
require "mygem/railtie" if defined? Rails

module MyGem
  # Code goes here...
end
```

my gemspec file is including the necessary files:

```
  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
  spec.files         = Dir["{lib}/**/*.rb"]
  spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.9"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 3.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rails", "~> 4.2"
```

I've tried various variations on this but for some reason or another I cannot seem to be able to call `.foo` on a given model. I am currently getting a NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecordExtension::ActiveSupport. Am I going about this incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Add `require 'active_support'` main file and you need add activesupport as a dependency I guess. Or just don't use ActiveSupport::Concern.

Comment: I've added `require 'active_support'` and `require 'active_record'` now but when I create a dummy Rails app and include the gem, bundle install, then try to do `Model.foo` from a console, I am getting: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'foo' for Model (call 'Model.connection' to establish a connection):Class`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell from this code. It looks like gem is not loaded. When I pasted code straight into rails console in any app it works fine.

Comment: I see that gems like Kaminari use `::ActiveRecord::Base`, perhaps I need to use that instead of `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: D'oh! I wasn't requiring it within my Rails app! Got it!

Comment: Cool, glad you found the problem.